# Inequality between measures: What can I say about the density function?

Tags: measure-theory

I have given two finite measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ on a measurable space $(\Omega,\Sigma)$ such that
$$
\nu(\Delta)\le\sqrt{\mu(\Delta)}\quad\text{for all }\Delta\in\Sigma.
$$
Obviously, $\nu$ is abs. continuous with respect to $\mu$. My question is: What I can say about the density function $f = d\nu/d\mu$? I first suspected that $f\in L^2(\mu)$. But this is false. A counterexample is given by $\Omega = (0,1)$, $\Sigma = $ Borel sigma algebra, $\mu = $ Lebesgue measure, $f(x) = 1/\sqrt x$, since
$$
\nu((a,b)) = \int_a^b x^{-1/2}\,dx = 2(\sqrt b - \sqrt a)\,\le\,2\sqrt{b-a} = 2\sqrt{\mu((a,b))},
$$
but obviously $f\notin L^2(0,1)$.

Does anyone know the/an answer?

Comment: You have only shown the estimate for intervals. Are you sure that this implies the same estimate on all Borel sets?

Comment: No, actually I don't... Now, I wonder whether there exists such a measure at all (except the zero measure).

Comment: There are such measures. Take $f \in L^2 (\mu) $ with $f\geq 0$ and $\|f\|_2\leq 1$ and note for $d\nu = f d\mu $ that $\nu (M) = \int 1_M f d\mu \leq \sqrt {\int 1_M^2d\mu}\sqrt {\int f^2d\mu}\leq \sqrt {\mu (M)} $. Conversely,  if your condition holds for $d\nu =fd\mu $, then we can take $M=\{f \geq \alpha\} $ to get $\alpha \mu (M)\leq \int_M fd\mu =\nu (M)\leq \sqrt {\mu (M)}$ and hence $\mu (M) \leq \alpha^2$ which means $f $ is weak $L^2$. I don't know if this last condition is also sufficient, however.

Comment: Thanks PhoemueX. But why $\mu(M)\le\alpha^2$? I deduce $\mu(M)\le 1/\alpha^2$ (which you might have meant). Is this the definition for "weak $L^2$"?

Comment: Oh,  yes it is. Sorry for the mistake.  See also the definition here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space.

Comment: Wow, thank you. I think that's it. If $f$ is weak $L^2$ then $$\sup_{M\in\Sigma,\,\mu(M) > 0}\frac{\nu(M)}{\mu(M)^{1/2}} = \sup_{M\in\Sigma,\,\mu(M) > 0}\frac{1}{\mu(M)^{1/2}}\int f d\mu\,\le\, C$$ due to Grafakos formula. Thus, there exists $C > 0$ such that $\nu(M)\le\sqrt{\mu(M)}$ for all $M\in\Sigma$ holds if and only if $f$ is weak $L^2$.

Comment: Do you agree? (Unfortunately, I cannot edit my comment after more than 5 minutes...) Can I change the bahaviour of the website? It also annoys me that I have to click on "2 more comments" in order to see them.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  To be honest, I had not noted that formula, I just wanted to refer to the definition. The only thing is that you probably meant $\nu (M)\leq C \sqrt {\mu (M)} $ in your last comment (note the $C $).

Comment: Exactly, thanks. And I also meant to put an $M$ under the integral. ;o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to PhoemueX, the question has been answered. The density functions $f$ generating such measures $\nu$ are exactly the weak $L^2$ functions with respect to $\mu$ (see the comments).